# Как сохранить данные из MySQL в CSV через PHP?

Tags: php

Есть база данных MySQL с одной таблицей с 10 столбцами. В таблице 1000+ записей.
Как можно сохранить эту таблицу в CSV через PHP? Например, нажали кнопку на определенной странице сайта и файл CSV начал загрузку на компьютер.

Comment: 1) получаем данные из mysql; 2) сохраняем их в [csv](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.fputcsv.php); 3) отдаем файл клиенту. Писать данные можно сразу в "вывод", таким образом пп. 2 и 3 можно объединить в один. Пример можно посмотреть [здесь](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16251849/4041128)

Comment: А как отдать файл клиенту? И потом удалить файл с сервера после загрузки?

Comment: Файл может быть простым потоком (например, `php://output`), посмотрите пример - там в updates он и используется

Comment: Не подскажите ещё, как сформировать массив из данных, полученных из базы?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

По комментарием пользователя @ВОРОН получается следующее:

```
<?php
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "username";
    $password = "password";
    $dbname = "myDB";

    header('Content-Type: application/csv');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="export.csv";');

    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);  // Создаем коннект к БД

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM my_table";  // SQL-запрос
    $result = $conn->query($sql);  // Выполняем запрос

    $fp = fopen('php://output', 'w');  // Открываем поток для записи

    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {  // Перебираем строки
        fputcsv($fp, $row, ";");  // Записываем строки в поток
    }

    $conn->close();  // Закрываем коннект к БД
?>
```